# code is not running on Kitkat version but works on Lollipop or higher platforms

Tags: android

code is not running on kitkat platform. but when it run on lollipop or higher platform it run without any error
here is the code

```
package com.digroof.whatslinkshare;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main_list extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
     Button b1,b2,b3,b4;

     @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) 
    findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent myIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            myIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody= "null";
            String sharesub="null";
            myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,shareBody);
            myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,sharesub);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent,"Share Using"));
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
     R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
    findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button10);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
    b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(Main_list.this,Discord_main.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(Main_list.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(Main_list.this,Facebook_main.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(Main_list.this,Telegram_main.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    }


   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    System.exit(0);
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_list, menu);
    return true;
    }

  @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.about_id) {
        Intent i=new Intent(this,about_Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
 @Override
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_addgroup) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Main_list.this,Usr_add.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }   if (id == R.id.nav_refresh) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Content View Refreshed Successful", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
      }
     }
```

activity_main_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main_list"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_list_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

content_main_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.digroof.whatslinkshare.Main_list"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main_list">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_marginBottom="163dp"
    android:text="DISCORD"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="147dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="128dp" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:text="WHATSAPP"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="147dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="128dp" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
    android:text="FACEBOOK"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="147dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="128dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:text="TELEGRAM"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="147dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="128dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

after lauching it on kitkat platform it showing below error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.digroof.whatslinkshare, PID: 26627
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.digroof.whatslinkshare/com.digroof.whatslinkshare.Main_list}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
       at com.digroof.whatslinkshare.Main_list.onCreate(Main_list.java:32)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
     at com.digroof.whatslinkshare.Main_list.onCreate(Main_list.java:32) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class ImageView
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
      at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:211)
      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:269)
      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:178)
      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:100)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
      at com.digroof.whatslinkshare.Main_list.onCreate(Main_list.java:32) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
      Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0200ad
       at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:204)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:332)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
                                                   at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:54)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:66)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
```

gradle info

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.digroof.whatslinkshare"
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 25
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

Answer (score 0):

If you run through the stack trace's causes you can see that it's failing to load the NavigationView.

Try reading the **Causes** of the stacktrace backwards to get a better idea of the reason.

1) Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class ImageView.

2) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

3) Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

This leads me to believe that within the NavigationView it is attempting to load an imageview that doesn't exist or has an incorrect ID.

I'd also assume that as it's happening during inflation it's to do with app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main_list".

Check your **nav_header_main_list** resource for an imageview with an incorrect ID.

Answer (score 0):

For remove error from Kitkat version you need to add following dependency into app level build.gradle.

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

Please put same version like 23.1.1 with other android dependency.